# How do I filter though an i loop of of Arrays

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to get an loop of Arrays.

```js
let findingArray = this.listNumber[i].GenericQuestions;
for (let k = 0; k < findingArray.length; k++) {
  let listArray = findingArray[k].Finding;
  console.log("listArray", listArray);
}
```

It returns all finding Arrays as expected.

[image]

What I would like to do is filter out all the empty Arrays from the loop.

All searches seem to point me to filtering inside the Array, but not filtering out empty Arrays.

Comment: What does _"filter out all the empty Arrays from the loop"_ mean? You don't want to log them? you want to remove them from the array? You want to create a new array without them? Be clear.

Comment: Why don't you add a if condition to check if array has some length or not inside the loop.

Comment: Have you tried `arr.filter(item => item.length)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript/lodash how to remove empty arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602661/javascript-lodash-how-to-remove-empty-arrays)

Comment: You can either add an `if` statement to your loop or use `arr.filter()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using your code, just put in an `if`. Empty arrays are those with length of 0.

```js
let findingArray = this.listNumber[i].GenericQuestions;
for (let k = 0; k < findingArray.length; k++) {
  let listArray = findingArray[k].Finding;
  if (listArray.length) { console.log("listArray", listArray); }
  // length of 0 coalesces to false
}
```

---

#### Alternatively, using `filter`:

Which is better because it's more readable (and thus understandable), shorter to write, and it's not destructive!

So `[1, 2, 3].filter(element => { element > 1 })` removes elements that do not satisfy the expression (result is `[2, 3]`). Supposing you have `let list = [ [], [1, 2, 3], [] ];` you can do `list.filter(element => { element.length > 0 })`. Filtering IS filtering the elements. In your case, the elements are other arrays, but it works the same way.

Do note one thing, `filter` is a pure, i.e. non-destructive, i.e. non-altering function; meaning it doesn't change the input, but returns a new copy. Perhaps that's what's bothering you. So:

```
let list = [ [], [1, 2, 3], [] ];
list.filter(element => { element.length > 0 });
console.log(list); // returns the original!

// instead
let newList = list.filter(element => { element.length > 0 });
console.log(newList); // returns the filtered list
```

And finally to update your full code, you can greatly simplify by doing something like this, which would be the same as your code (depending on some details not visible in your snippet, but generally the point is, try to push for this style):

```
console.log( listNumber
  .map(i => i.GenericQuestions)
  .map(i => i.Finding)
  .filter(i => i.length) );
// as you can see, each step takes in the the result of previous array
// meaining they're chainable, which is pretty sweet
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is using Array.isArray and then finding length. The up voted answer has some really great information and will also upvote, but what worked with my code is

```
    let findingArray = this.listNumber[i].GenericQuestions;
      for(let k = 0; k < findingArray.length; k++){ 
        let listArray = findingArray[k].Finding;
        if (Array.isArray(listArray) && listArray.length) {
         console.log("listArray", listArray);
        }
      }
```